# jquery multiple selector return wrong result rather than execute it one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function which will return true or false

```
$.fn.valForm = function(){
  if($(this).val().length < $(this).attr("minLength"))
  {
    alert("false");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("true");
  }
};
```

execute it for multiple selector (4)

```
$("#txtFirst, #txtLast, #txtNick, #txtEmail").valForm();
```

it resulted 1 time alert only

I need it resulted 4 time alert like this

```
$("#txtFirst").valForm();
$("#txtLast").valForm();
$("#txtNick").valForm();
$("#txtEmail").valForm();
```

how to do that more simple?

Comment: [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin is not written to handle this.

Whenever you do a plugin, always add `return this.each`, ie:

```
$.fn.valForm = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    if($(this).val().length < $(this).attr("minLength"))
    {
      alert("false");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("true");
    }
  });
};
```